# Heroku assets rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, assets

I have just deployed a new app on heroku for the first time.

Unlike many others I had no troubles precompiling the assets. They are neatly precompiled and placed in
`public/assets`. I verified this in heroku bash terminal.

However when I open the project web page none of my assets are served. I verified that the hash to avoid cache stuff was correct.

I have in my `application.rb` added `config.serve_static_assets = true` but it made no difference.

There `public/assets/manifest.json` (pointing to the right files) but no `yml` and I think I read somewhere about a manifest.yml. Could this be the problem?

Any advice on how to debug this? Or what might be wrong.

#### Edit

In answer to the comment an example:

There is a file in the heroku app (checked with heroku bash)
`public/assets/application-7744776478cb6ee3a23dd79bfcc293bd.css`

my browser asks the heroku app for:
´assets/application-7744776478cb6ee3a23dd79bfcc293bd.css´
and the heroku app answers with 404 file not found.

Comment: this is a good problem description, unfortunately you are missing important details about the missing assets. a) how are the asset paths rendered? b) do you get 404s? c) can you find those files on heroku?

Comment: Did my edit fill in the blanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding the gem rails_12factor

suggested in: [heroku assets not found 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323409/heroku-assets-not-found-404)