# Heroku[router] making GET request to "/assets/bundle.js.map"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku

Getting a weird error in my heroku logs:

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/bundle.js.map" host=syndicator1.herokuapp.com request_id=106a2ab1-c373-4e2c-817a-f740a2e0819b fwd="24.102.93.192" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=23ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/bundle.js.map" 

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/bundle.js.map"):
```

I have no idea where this is coming from, I just know that my application isn't behaving the way it is in development. Any idea where to start fixing this?

EDIT:

The application works, mostly, in production. What doesn't work is the error-handling.

Here is what happens when I try to submit my form in development with invalid values:

[image: error box]

Basically my Error-Box component gets triggered.

This is what happens when I do the same in production. 
The Error-Box component does not get triggered. The 422 is correct, I want that but it should be triggering the error-box, instead I get the following in console:

[image: console]

Here is the code in the component that should trigger the error box,

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {addEvents,toggleModal,handleError} = this.props;
    axios.post('/events', {
        event: this.state
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        const event = response.data.event;
        toggleModal();
        addEvents(event);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        handleError(error.response.data);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide us some information? However, it seems like this [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323409/heroku-assets-not-found-404#20433875)

Comment: That was already in the gemfile by default so doesnt seem to be the problem. Check the edit.